# Tracking mouse inside of a terminal

Tags: python

I am using a raspberry pi and want to see where my mouse is (not my mouse on the screen because i have none but my mouse on the table). I need to see a grid that has x y from (0, 0) to say (1000, 1000) and in python. 
I've tried using "pynput" and other methods but they are tracking the mouse on the screen. Is there a way to write the code out so i can just print coordinates of where my physical mouse is not my virtual one?
I don't believe this is a duplicate because even after clicking on every link in google for the first couple pages i have got nothing working. Maybe im not wording my question right and this is easy to do, please help!

Comment: So you want to track the physical location of your mouse? How? Using a camera? Using sensors in the mouse? I also don't understand why the title asks about "tracking [the] mouse inside of a terminal" while the question itself seems to talk about something entirely different. I believe this question needs further clarification.

Comment: i need a x and y coordinate of a mouse plugged into the usb port of a raspberry pi. No sensors the data sent in from the mouse should be able to be interpreted so i can get a location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pynput` is the wrong module to use: you need the access to the kernel's input event stream via [`python-evdev`](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Normal mice provide relative output, not absolute output, so you won't know where the mouse is on the table. You can calibrate the relative measurements provided by your mouse to be able to tell that e.g. the mouse outputs 1200 units per inch of motion, so that if you get an `EV_REL` event from the Linux input subsystem, you can translate the units into physical units. See [Linux Input Subsystem userspace API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/input/input_uapi.html). Note that as of 1/2019, the most recent [Raspbian uses Linux kernel 4.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian#Version_history).

A touchscreen would provide absolute input, and you can certainly take the capacitive input panel, put it on the table, stick a little circular aluminum sticker on the bottom of the mouse (or a hockey puck, or ...), and use that as a makeshift absolute input device.